# Pyspark: apply a function to matching partitions of multiple dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two Spark DataFrames, with matching pairs of partitions. I'd like to send each pair of partitions to a different executor and perform a Python function on them.

If I just had one DataFrame, I could use `mapPartitions`, but then I couldn't access the other one. I've tried broadcasting the second one, but it's too large to fit on my executors without partitioning.

I think that I probably need to use a function from [pyspark.rdd.RDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/api/pyspark/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html), but I'm not sure which one. Several options, like `groupByKey` and `cogroup` seem like they could be relevant, but I don't understand how they could be applied to a DataFrame object.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Here's my input data (each color is a partition):

[image: input data]

And here's what I'd like to do:

[image: mapping over matching pairs of partitions]

Comment: I'm confused, it sounds like what you want to do is join df1 and df2 on the partition column. Is this not an option for some reason?

Comment: Hey, thanks for checking. If I understand correctly, that would create one row for every combination of rows in df1 and df2. So if each df has a million rows in a given partition, the joined df would have a trillion rows. I'm hoping to do this without all of that duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You could nest each dataframe before joining.

This might look something like (below is in pyspark):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

grouped1 = sdf1. \
    select(partition_by, F.struct(*[col for col in sdf1.columns if col != partition_by]).alias('_data')). \
    groupBy(partition_by). \
    agg(F.collect_list('_data').alias('data'))

grouped2 = sdf2. \
    select(partition_by, F.struct(*[col for col in sdf2.columns if col != partition_by]).alias('_data')). \
    groupBy(partition_by). \
    agg(F.collect_list('_data').alias('data'))

merged = grouped1.join(grouped2, on=partition_by)
```

Then you could apply your function like `merged.rdd.map(f)`.

I'd be curious if anyone knows about the performance implications of this vs. alternative approaches.